# Merge the specific rows in one column sql

Tags: mysql

I want to merge specific rows in the column, but I couldn't do that !

For Example,

I have three tables which are:

- **Table 1**: `ID, Name1`
- **Table 2**: `ID, Table1Id, Table3Id`
- **Table 3**: `ID, Name2`

The data in the tables will be as the following:

```
Table 1                     table 2                     Table 3

ID - Name             ID- Table1Id- Table2ID             ID - Name
1 - A                       1 - 1 - 1                     1 - AE
2 - B                       2 - 1 - 2                     2 - AF
                            3 - 2 - 1
```

When I did the join the table will be:

Joined Table:

```
    table1Name - Table3Name
             A - AE
             A - AF
             B - AE
```

I want the table looks like that >>>

```
Table
    Table1Name - Table3Name
        A - AE, AF
        B - AE
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

```
select tb1.name nameTb1, tb3.name nameTb3
  from table2 tb2
 inner join table1 tb1 on tb2.Table1Id = tb1.id
 inner join table3 tb3 on tb2.Table3Id = tb3.id
```

Comment: This answer was posted before the OP edited the question with the "I want the table looks like that".

Answer (score 0):

What database you are using?

Try to look at `CONCAT`.

So it will something like this on select field.

```
CONCAT(TABLE1.NAME, '-', TABLE3.NAME)
```

For that case, here is your code

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',table1.name , GROUP_CONCAT(table3.name SEPARATOR ',')) tablename
  FROM table2
 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.Table1Id = table1.id
 INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.Table3Id = table3.id
GROUP BY table1.name
```